# How to make typescript know exact constant value for single property of my object?

Tags: typescript

I'm struggling with that for a while.
My problem is as follows:
I have known data structure.

```
const array = [
 {
    foo: "foo1" as const,
    bar: "any string"
    baz: 2
 },
 {
    foo: "foo2" as const,
    bar: "any string 2"
    baz: 2
 }
]
```

Can I simply infer types to have only `foo` variable autocompleted with exact value?

`array[0].foo // has possible values of "foo1", "foo2"`

but

`array[0].bar // has any string as a value`

`array[0].baz // has any number as a value`

Let's say I have interface with known some types:

```
interface Example {
   name: ???? // how should i type it?
   bar: string,
   baz: number,
}
```

I'm trying to archive that without declaring type for all the possible names.
I would be grateful for any suggestions.

---

Edit:

I tried with parametrizing the Example interface:

```
interface Example<Name> { name: Name, ... rest of types }
type MapToNamed<T> = T extends { name: infer Name } ? Example <Name> : never
type TargetType = MapToNamed<typeof array[number]>;
```

But that one force me to use `as any as MapToNamed<typeof array>` and I am not sure if that is correct.

Comment: `foo: ‘foo1’ | ‘foo2’`?

Comment: Yes, that's true, but there will be like 20 strings there. Those strings will be known on compilation time.

Comment: `{ name: infer Name }` what is `Name` type in your context? @kperwel

Answer (score 1):

`"foo1" as const` is called [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) which is for read-only values

For your case, it does not affect your type declaration

You can define `Example` like below

```
interface Example {
   foo: string, //apply for all string types
   bar: string,
   baz: number,
}

const array: Example[] = [
 {
    foo: "foo1" as const, //consider as a read-only string
    bar: "any string",
    baz: 2
 },
 {
    foo: "foo2" as const, //consider as a read-only string
    bar: "any string 2",
    baz: 2
 }
] 

console.log({ array })
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIA84FsAOAbFAbwChkyYB7CgLmQGcwpQBzAGlLICM4paGmQbDsm4AvWiACuWTtHYBfYsQQUQDZDyhwAnrQzZ8EANoBdZAF5kR0iTLkqtAESUKARkca6yFWrDs7IjxOcCDa9Iwsjv52YrQATKTy-rZ2Lk4ucR5wXj4M0VxByI4hYfwsyJn5geIVicRmSrkUBAB0eBTMABSEGlBaYfIAlEA)

If you want to have fixed type like `foo1` and `foo2`. You can use [enum type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html)

```
enum Foo {
  "foo1",
  "foo2"
}

interface Example {
   foo: keyof typeof Foo, //"foo1" | "foo2"
   bar: string,
   baz: number,
}

const array: Example[] = [
 {
    foo: "foo1" as const,
    bar: "any string",
    baz: 2
 },
 {
    foo: "foo2" as const,
    bar: "any string 2",
    baz: 2
 }
] 

console.log({ array })
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAYg9nKBvAUFKAiAZggjBgGjUxzgCYMUBfFFASxABdgAnLAQwGNgoBRAD3YQADgBseqdFFIAuKAGtgATzhYojJcOCrYCIlIBG7FnIDOjFgwDm%209EYBec8BAOsiNFJzghzUYy3YlOQEhMWAAbQBdKABeKHC0SSlZEjwMP1MoLx9GWztjOQx2ECUoc0sQK0JifMcoMjQqfST0FOwECgys73M8qCMTTGLS8ut66ql%209jqGqBpo2mzTOHEAOlE4KwAKJD8WANKqAEogA)

Comment: I didn't notice that it is already completing the code. :| So, TypeScript gets as narrow completion as it can?

This one fulfills my needs. Thanks a lot. In the future, I'll try to make it throw an error if the wrong string is provided.

Comment: You're welcome!~. By the way, what do you mean `narrow completion`?  @kperwel

Comment: It is working fine, if I allow typescript to infer all the types. The problem still occurs if I have only certain property typed, and want to have name inferred. `const array: Example[]` hides constant names and autocompletion is not working.

By "narrow" i meant that if I set `"value" as const` for string it'll know what I want there. But it not.

Comment: Could you give that example in your question? I may find a way to help you out on that. @kperwel